# Converting back from bitwise yield wrong expected value (Solved)

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I'm trying to convert back from a byte buffer to it corresponding ulong, but can't recreate the value... I must be blind or doing something wrong here :(

```
ulong us = (ulong)(millisecondsSinceUnixEpoch * 1000.0);

// xxxxxxxx-xxxx-0000-0000-000000000000
_buffer[0] = (byte)(us >> 40);
_buffer[1] = (byte)(us >> 32);
_buffer[2] = (byte)(us >> 24);
_buffer[3] = (byte)(us >> 16);
_buffer[4] = (byte)(us >> 8);
_buffer[5] = (byte)us;


ulong reUs = ((ulong)_buffer[0] << 40) |
             ((ulong)_buffer[1] << 32) |
             ((ulong)_buffer[2] << 24) |
             ((ulong)_buffer[3] << 16) |
             ((ulong)_buffer[4] << 8) |
             _buffer[5];

Debug.WriteLine(us);
Debug.WriteLine(reUs);
```

Results in:

> 1691334871851000 (us)

> 2485011587064 (reUs)

Expecting that (reUs == us)

Comment: A `ulong` is 64 bits - 8 bytes. You're trying to store it in 6 bytes... you're basically "losing" the top two bytes.

Comment: Your input value is 0x00_06_02_42_96_3b_9f_f8. Your result is 0x00_00_02_42_96_3b_9f_f8... as you can see, the least significant 6 bytes are being preserved.

Comment: `1691334871851000` needs 51 bits to store, which does not fit in your 6 bytes buffer

Comment: You guys are right! Dam... Now I see my problem, I was already passing milliseconds but wrongly using *1000 from seconds to make the conversion to ms, making that won't fit in my 6 bytes. Removing the *1000 fix the problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As replies told, I'm losing a byte making number to not match. That is due my wrong calculation to turn seconds into milliseconds which is not necessary since the value already came in ms unit! The correct code is:

```
    _buffer[0] = (byte)(millisecondsSinceUnixEpoch >> 40);
    _buffer[1] = (byte)(millisecondsSinceUnixEpoch >> 32);
    _buffer[2] = (byte)(millisecondsSinceUnixEpoch >> 24);
    _buffer[3] = (byte)(millisecondsSinceUnixEpoch >> 16);

    _buffer[4] = (byte)(millisecondsSinceUnixEpoch >> 8);
    _buffer[5] = (byte)millisecondsSinceUnixEpoch;


    ulong reUs = ((ulong)_buffer[0] << 40) |
                 ((ulong)_buffer[1] << 32) |
                 ((ulong)_buffer[2] << 24) |
                 ((ulong)_buffer[3] << 16) |
                 ((ulong)_buffer[4] << 8) |
                 _buffer[5];
```